# why Char* has length = 1 when structure containing vector are copied into it using memcpy. DO we have alternative apporach

Tags: c++, c, char, structure

I have structure which contains other sub structures that are stored in vector . Now I Want to copy that structure into char* . I did via memcpy .

ON debugging I found that char* has lenght = 1 ? why is that ?

below are my example

```
      struct test_A
    {
        char a;
        char b;
        char c;
        char d;
    };

    struct st_main
    {
        short int val;
        short int val1;
        std::vector< test_A> sub;
    };

    int main()
    {

    st_main t1;
    t1.val = 2;
    t1.val1= 2;

    test_A test;
    test.a = 'A';
    test.b = 'A';
    test.c = 'A';
    test.d = 'A';
    test_A test2;
    test2.a = 'B';
    test2.b = 'B';
    test2.c = 'B';
    test2.d = 'B';
    t1.sub.push_back( test2 );
    t1.sub.push_back( test );
    char textchar[70];

    std::cout << " the len of struct --> " <<sizeof( t1 ) << std::endl;
    memcpy( textchar,  &t1, sizeof( t1) );
    std::cout << " the len of textchar --> " << strlen( textchar ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }

o/p:
 the len of struct --> 24
 the len of textchar --> 1
```

Comment: Probably because there is a `0` in the structure somewhere.

Comment: Why would you copy a `vector` with `memcpy`? It copies the pointer(s) to the memory holding the elements, but not the elements themselves.

Comment: @juanchopanza, well I dont think so I hvae zero here , but in real code yes  unsigned char can have 0 value as well

Comment: You have a `0`. But `strlen` is not the right tool to use here.

Comment: @T.C  so how would I copy structure into const char*. All the other code in same project uses the same approach like copying teh structure into char* so I am not advised to change it all. yes, only in my case I use vectors in structure

Comment: @juanchopanza, Ok Agreed , i Have zerobuT i am wondering whats teh solution? is it like I cant able to use vectors in structure ?

Comment: What is the problem which you need a solution to?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I want to copy structure into char* so that I use that value from char* in other functions. in Actual code , I have chain of functions which depends on char* so I proabably cant able to chnage that.

Comment: That's a very vague description of your problem. Please go into more detail about exactly what your problem is. But not here, in another post. The question in this post has already been answered.

Comment: THanks everyone for the valuable input.I will try to figure out something in case if I couldnt I wil raise it in another topic

Answer (score 3):

The second byte in `t1`'s memory is 0.  `t1.val` is a `short`, and 2 is stored in a `short` as `0x02 0x00` on your machine.  Thus `textchar[0]` is 0x02 and `textchar[1]` is 0x00.

Comment: Thanks for expaling , wondering how would i solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

strlen counts the number of characters until it finds a zero ('\0'). So if your data contains a byte whose value is zero, strlen will stop.
t1 first field, val is a short int and you set it to 2, so you will have the characters 0 and 2 (or 2 and 0 according to endianess) in memory, and strlen will stop.
Note that when you copy a vector with memcpy you don't really know what will happen, the vector will have an internal representation containing pointers so that you will not store the content of the vector (memcpying back to another struct will probably lead to crashes).
If you want a data structure that can be easily serialized to a buffer (and unserialized from), I'd suggest google protocol buffers.